# How to add List value at caret position in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add list values at cursor caret position in a contenteditable division. I have set of some buttons and list. I am able to add buttons value at caret position but list values are not getting add at cursor caret position.Please help me. Below is the code :

```
 function insertAtCursor(input) {
        document.getElementById('mytext').focus();
        var sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();
                textNode = document.createTextNode(input + " ");
                range.insertNode(textNode);
                range.setStart(textNode, textNode.length);
                range.setEnd(textNode, textNode.length);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
        else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            document.selection.createRange().text = input;
        }
    }
    $('.add_val').on('click', function () {
        var input = $(this).attr('id');
        insertAtCaret(input);

    });


<li>Payment Processing
                                              <div class="expander"></div>
                                                <ul> @foreach (var item in Model.PP_Field_List)
                                                     {
                                                         if(Model.prslist == "PaymentProcess")
                                                         {
                                                        <li class="add_val" id="@item.Value.Replace(" ", String.Empty)">@item.Text.Split('_')[0]&nbsp<span>(@item.Text.Split('_')[1])</span></li>   
                                                         }                            
                                                     }

                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
```